# Geographical proximity aggregation in ElasticSearch instead of geohash?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently using geohash aggregation, but I'd like to have my pins aggregated by density/priximity rather than by predefined sections - is that even possible with ES?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible by elasticsearch using `decay` functions. You can read more about them [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay).

Sample from elasticsearch docs

```
"DECAY_FUNCTION": { 
    "FIELD_NAME": { 
          "origin": "11, 12",
          "scale": "2km",
          "offset": "0km",
          "decay": 0.33
    } }
```